# How to get classes labels from cross_val_predict used with predict_proba in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I need to train a [Random Forest classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) using a 3-fold cross-validation. For each sample, I need to retrieve the prediction probability when it happens to be in the test set.

I am using scikit-learn version 0.18.dev0.

This new version adds the feature to use the method [cross_val_predict()](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict) with an additional parameter `method` to define which kind of prediction require from the estimator.

In my case I want to use the [predict_proba()](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) method, which returns the probability for each class, in a multiclass scenario.

However, when I run the method, I get as a result the matrix of prediction probabilities, where each rows represents a sample, and each column represents the prediction probability for a specific class.

The problem is that the method does not indicate which class corresponds to each column.

The value I need is the same (in my case using a `RandomForestClassifier`) returned in the attribute classes_ defined as:

> classes_ : array of shape = [n_classes] or a list of such arrays
>   The classes labels (single output problem), or a list of arrays of class labels (multi-output problem).

which is needed by `predict_proba()` because in its documentation it is written that:

> The order of the classes corresponds to that in the attribute classes_.

A minimal example is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

X = np.random.randn(10, 10)
y = y = np.array([1] * 4 + [0] * 3 + [2] * 3)

# how to get classes from here?
proba = cross_val_predict(estimator=clf, X=X, y=y, method="predict_proba")

# using the classifier without cross-validation
# it is possible to get the classes in this way:
clf.fit(X, y)
proba = clf.predict_proba(X)
classes = clf.classes_
```

Comment: For cases where you won't have access to `y`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have access to `y` but I don't know in which order the labels are sorted. I may speculate that they are sorted in ascending order but I am not completely sure.

Comment: sorry, I don't have 0.18 yet so I can't test this, and it may be obvious, but doesn't the `clf` object now contain a `classes_` attribute?

Comment: Np. No, I tested it and it doesn't have the `classes_` attribute. Maybe the classifier is copied inside the `cross_val_predict()` method and the original is not updated.

Comment: You're right! It [does](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/db56cf4/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L409).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they will be in sorted order; this is because `DecisionTreeClassifier` (which is the default `base_estimator` for `RandomForestClassifier`) [uses `np.unique` to construct the `classes_` attribute](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L193) which returns the sorted unique values of the input array.

Comment: That's nice to hear :) Thanks. So if I use `np.unique` before calling I should get the same `classes_` attribute?

Comment: yep i think that should do it

Comment: What about other classifiers though? Are the classes always guaranteed to be in the label order?

Comment: @simon i would imagine so, but unfortuately this is implemented separately for each classifer (i.e. the code is not shared), so you'll have to check case-by-case if you need to be certain